# How do I get filtered list item into chart web part?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Using Sharepoint 2010 :-I have three Web parts in my page :
1) Chart web part 2) list filter web Part and 3) List web part
my requirement is that I can apply filter on list web part and when I get the result by filtering list ,I want the Chart of only that filtered List Items in Chart web part.
Please give me suggestion ...
I have tried applying filter on list then done connection of that list with chart web part but each time it is showing the chart of all items not the chart of filtered one.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did anyone find an answer or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but here are some additional details that may be helpful:

I had 3 web parts on my page: a Chart, a List, and a List Filter.  The chart was connected to the list web part (not to the list itself) and the list filter also connected to the list web part.  If I used the list filter web part, it applied the filter to the list web part as expected, but the chart did not change.  However, if I applied a filter in the list web part directly, that did cause the chart to update.  So I removed the list filter web part from the page.

Now I have just the list and the chart web parts, and simply the restriction that I can't filter any given column to more than one value (that's all that is possible using the filter dropdowns on a list's header row).

I did discover another problem there, though: if my list exceeds the item limit, the paging buttons don't work while the list web part is connected to the chart.